# Force syntax at file open with Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I would like to open a file in Sublime Text from another application. I need to open XML files with extensions not registered by Sublime Text, but I would like to avoid that users have to configure things by doing as much as possible from the command-line.  My users can be fluent with a text editor but they are not developers so too much tweaking in profile files might overwhelm them.

Is it possible from command-line arguments do the following things?

a) Enforce a syntax for a file, even if its extension is not currently registered in Sublime Text.

b) Enforce that "highlight_line" = true for this file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe make a package that you can "place" in the correct location (like Packages/User) if it's not there already when you run your code.

For a) Enforce a syntax for a file
You can make a file named XML.sublime-settings and place something like this inside

```
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "newext"
    ],
    "highlight_line": true // this is for b)

}
```